# unable to establish connection from cgi using Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP

Tags: perl, cgi, lighttpd

I've tried to send message via `Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP`. Everything ok when I do it with a standalone script like this:

```
my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new({
  host => ...,
  ssl =>1,
  port => 465,
  localport => 10000,
  sasl_username => '...',
  sasl_password => '...',
});

my $email = Email::Simple->create(
  header => [
    To      => '...',
    From    => '...',
    Subject => '...',
  ],
  body => "message",
);

eval {sendmail($email, { transport => $transport })};
```

But when I try to execute it as cgi (on lighttpd server), I receive the error `unable to establish SMTP connection`.. Is this trouble of lighttpd? Any ideas are very welcome! Thanks in advance, people!

Comment: you ever solve this?